# Using the percentage symbol as a user input in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, symbols

If I want the user to input an interest rate in the format of : n% (n is a floating point number).

Given that % is not a valid number to be input, is there a way to nevertheless get the user input and then perform the necessary conversions?

Basically is there a way in which the following code can actually work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CanThisWork{

 public static void main(String[] args){

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Annual Interest Rate");

  //user input is 5.4% for example

  //this is where the problem is because a double data type cannot contain the % symbol:
  double rate = input.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("Your Annual rate " + rate + " is an error");
 }
}
```

All jokes aside, I would love to get a solution to this predicament

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter Annual Interest Rate");

      //user input is 5.4% for example

      //this is where the problem is because a double data type cannot contain the % 
      symbol:

      String userInput = input.nextLine(); // "5.4%"

      double percentage = Double.parseDouble(userInput.replace("%", "")) / 100; // 0.54
      //You can now do calculations or anything you want with this value.

     //multiplying it with 100 to get it to % again
      System.out.println("Your Annual rate " + percentage*100 + "% is an error");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `5.4%` is not a `Double`, you would have to use `Scanner` methods that reads String as input like `next` or `nextLine`. But to can ensure that the String that is being read is a double ending with %, you can use `hasNext(String pattern)` method.

```
if (input.hasNext("^[0-9]{1,}(.[0-9]*)?%$")) {
        String inputString = input.next();
        double rate = Double.parseDouble(inputString.substring(0, inputString.length() - 1));
        System.out.println("Your Annual rate " + rate + " is an error");
    }

   // Pattern explanation 
   ^ - Start of string
   [0-9]{1,} - ensure that at least one character is number
   [.[0-9]*]* - . can follow any number which can be followed by any number
   %$ - ensure that string must end with %
```

Above code will ensure that only `Double` number ending with `%` are passed through

Comment: There would not be parse exception as string having multiple. will not go inside if clause

Comment: @user85421 - Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my pattern and this seems to resolve the issue that you pointed out

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is not a double anymore you can't use `input.nextDouble()` instead, you need to get it as a string, replace the '%' and then parse it as a double.

```
double rate = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine().replace("%",""));
```